# Activate buttons at the top on each div?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tell them to query, I want to show three buttons at the top on the right when positioning the pointer cursor, and hide the buttons when drawing the pointer cursor out of the div.

Just like this picture.

[image]

Comment: Do you mind sharing your code with us to position buttons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap groups labels and inputs together in a `form-group` element.  So, assuming a structure like this...

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="button-wrapper">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
  <label for="exampleInput">Label 01</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInput">
</div>
```

You can hide the `button-wrapper` div and show it on hover by targeting the parent's `:hover` state.

```
.button-wrapper {
  display: none;
}

.form-group:hover .button-wrapper {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Where did you add the CSS style hover ..?

Comment: @Hernando `:hover` is the pseudo-selector responsible for detecting the cursor. You want to add it to the parent component so the buttons will show even if the user is not hovering exactly over the buttons themselves, as you said, so I've added it to `.form-group` on the second block of rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library to get it easily:

http://paulkinzett.github.io/toolbar/

Answer (score 0):

The general idea is to put the icons inside of the box, position them outside of the box, hide them by default, and show them with a `:hover` pseudo class.

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
body {
  padding-top: 2em;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  display: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
div:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>
    <li>c</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```